# How to draw the outline of an icon made of several polygons?

Tags: graphics, regions, polygons, drawing

I have an icon defined like that:

```
speakerIcon = Graphics[{
    Triangle[{{0, -1}, {1,1},{-1,1}}],
    Rectangle[{-1, -1},{1, 0}]
}, ImageSize->20]
```

I can display that icon in an arbitrary color by wrapping it inside `Show`:

```
Show[Graphics[FaceForm[Pink]], speakerIcon]
```

But how to draw only the outline of the icon?
Using `EdgeForm` does not work since it displays the outline of each component of the graphic object:

```
Show[
    Graphics[FaceForm[]],
    Graphics[EdgeForm[{Thick,Blue}]], 
    speakerIcon, ImageSize->100
]
```

[image]

FWIW, I suspect I didn't follow the "right" path by defining my region as a `Graphics`. Maybe using `Region` would have been better? I'm open to any suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Mathematica 12 a possible approach is `OuterPolygon`:

```
pol = Polygon[{{{0, -1}, {1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, {{-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {1, 
     0}, {-1, 0}}}]
Graphics[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[{Thick, Blue}], pol}]
```

[image]

```
Graphics[{FaceForm[], EdgeForm[{Thick, Blue}], OuterPolygon[pol]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Merci beaucoup André! I still have to try it, but I think I will follow that path (pun intended) because, as I explained in a comment to the @kglr's answer, I'm somewhat uncomfortable in constantly converting from graphics to regions and back.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics.html):

```
bdg = BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics @ speakerIcon
```

[image]

```
Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Black, Thin}], FaceForm[], MeshPrimitives[bdg, 2]}, ImageSize -> 30]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use [`BoundaryDiscretizeRegion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BoundaryDiscretizeRegion.html) + [`RegionUnion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionUnion.html):

```
bdr = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[
  RegionUnion[Triangle[{{0, -1}, {1, 1}, {-1, 1}}], Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 0}]]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @kglr. One side comment: when drawing shapes, I noticed I often have to convert between `Graphics` objects and `Region`, in one direction or the other. I read regions are a recent addition to Mathematica. Does that mean a rule of thumb would be to use them exclusively and considering `Graphics` only to render the output? On the other hand, it seems quite a waste of resources to convert even the simplest polygons to mesh objects.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux, TIL from andre's answer that it may not be necessary to go through `Region` for some shapes.